# A way to add points to a spline in KineticJS?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, spline

Is there a way to add points to an existing spline in KineticJS? Right now, I have to call `destroy()` on the spline and create a whole new one when adding points. I'm hoping there's a better way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add at the end of line.

```
line.attrs.points.push({x:100, y:20})
layer.draw()
```

If you want to add at the middle of line, you need to use a function to rebuild the points. i.e. sort by x points

---- for Spline (Edited) --

```
spline.attrs.points.push({x:10,y:10})
spline.setPoints(spline.attrs.points); 
layer.draw();
```

Comment: I get this error, `TypeError: f[0] is undefined`. Seems like your mechanism makes sense, but it only works for the first 2 points. The third point causes an error and the spline vanishes.

Comment: don't know why spline uses allPoints instead of points to draw it with tension. However if you set whole points again, it will work. just one more line. answer is edited.

Comment: yes, that's basically what I did (referenced in my answer to my own question here). I keep a reference to the points array anyway for other reasons though.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the `setPoints` method from the `Line` class that `Spline` can use. That works much better, I don't have to destroy the spline and recreate it. If someone has a better answer that'd be great. I was hoping for a hidden `add(point)` method...

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
 spline.setPoints(spline.getPoints().push({x:10,y:10}));
```

or create a quick function:

```
 function addPoint(spline, point){
      spline.setPoints(spline.getPoints().push(point); 
 }
```